# How can I keep selected Bootstrap 5 PILL on page refresh?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a problem with the implementation of the active tab after refreshing the page. I need to make the last active tab remain after the page refresh.

**What i do**

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills product-additional-info-tabas me-3" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a href="#basic" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-dimensions-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-dimensions" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-dimensions" aria-selected="true">Basic Information</a>
        <a href="#description"  class="nav-link" id="v-pills-description-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-description" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-description" aria-selected="false">Descriptions</a>
        <a href="#image" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-images-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-images" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-images" aria-selected="false">Images & Video</a>
        <a href="#price" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-price-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-price" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-price" aria-selected="false">Prices</a>
        <a href="#inventory" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-inventory-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-inventory" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-inventory" aria-selected="false">Inventory</a>
        <a href="#attributes" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-attributes-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-attributes" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-attributes" aria-selected="false">Attributes</a>
        <a href="#shipping" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-shipping-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-shipping" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-shipping" aria-selected="false">Shipping</a>
        <a href="#volumetric" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-volumetric-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-volumetric" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-volumetric" aria-selected="false">Volumetrics</a>
        <a href="#warranty" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-warranty-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-warranty" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-warranty" aria-selected="false">Warranty</a>
        <a href="#related" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-related-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-related" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-related" aria-selected="false">Related Products</a>
        <a href="#seo" class="nav-link" id="v-pills-seo-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-seo" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-seo" aria-selected="false">SEO</a>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
  $(function() {
                $('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                    localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
                });
                var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
                if (lastTab) {
                    $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
                }
            });
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: In your jQuery script, you have `data-toggle`, but the data attribute in the nav div uses `data-bs-toggle`. Try changing it to include the -bs-. Also, if you don't have to use jQuery for anything else, you could do it with vanilla JavaScript.